# unknown type name '_declspec' on cmake

Tags: cmake, android-ndk, dllexport

I am trying to generate a shared native library using cmake. the contents of this library are nothing more than native functions that will later be used in Unity. that is why the functions have the extension __declspec (dllexport) so that in the Unity section they can be called with dllImport.

My problem comes when I try to compile that library in cmake. I am using Ninja as compiled and cross-compiled with Android toolchain. The problem is that it tells me:

```
../InnovaeInterface/include/Camara.h:7:2: error: unknown type name '_declspec'
    _declspec(dllexport) CameraUtils::Calibration* createCamara(void);
    ^
../InnovaeInterface/include/Camara.h:7:22: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
    _declspec(dllexport) CameraUtils::Calibration* createCamara(void);
                        ^
```

The truth is that I have no idea where to throw. I hope you help me.

Comment: Have you tried adding `-fdeclspec` to your cFlags/cppFlags?

Comment: i dont find any information about that, ca you put me an example?

Comment: Just add it wherever you're setting your other C and C++ compiler flags (either in your build.gradle or in one of your CMakeList.txt files).

Comment: Please include in your question the contents of the toolchain file you used. Also, do you have the freedom to change the shared library's code and CMakeLists.txt files?